# Why is my paragraph out of my body?

Tags: html, css, size

```css
html, body {cursor:url(files/cursor.cur),progress;height:100%;}
html{background-color:blue;background-image:url(files/bg.jpg);background-attachment:fixed;background-position:center;background-size:cover;}
body{width:80%;background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.75);margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;}
p{margin-right:10px;margin-left:10px;text-align: center;}
iframe{overflow:hidden;height:80%;width:100%;}
img{display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}
table{border-collapse:collapse;font-family:calibri;border-style:outset;border-color:#FFFF00;border-width:5px;}
td{font-size:16px;border-width:1px;border-style:solid;border-color:#FFFF00;background-color:#FFFFFF}
th{font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;background-color:#FFEE00;border-color:#FFFF00;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;}
a.active{background-color:#0088FF !important;}
a.active:hover{background-color:#00AAFF !important;}
.font1{font-family:calibri;font-size:16px;}
.font2{font-family:calibri;font-size:18px;text-decoration:underline;}
#menu1 a{display:block;background-color:#0066FF;text-decoration:none;font-family:calibri;font-size:20px;color:#FFFFFF;padding:10px 10px;} 
#menu1 a:hover{background-color:#00AAFF;} 
#menu1 li{display:inline-block;} 
#menu1 ul{list-style:none;text-align:center;margin:0 auto;padding:0px;}
#menu2 a{display:block;background-color:#0066FF;text-decoration:none;font-family:calibri;font-size:16px;color:#FFFFFF;padding:10px 10px;} 
#menu2 a:hover{background-color:#00AAFF;} 
#menu2 li{display:inline-block;}
#menu2 ul{list-style:none;text-align:center;margin:0 auto;padding:0px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>De Geoclub</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <br>
        <div id="menu1"><ul><li><a href="index.html">Welkom</a></li><li><a href="agenda.html">Agenda</a></li><li><a href="fotos.html">Foto's</a></li><li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li></ul></div>
        <p><span class="font2">De Geoclub</span><br><br><span class="font1">Welkom op de website van de Geoclub. De Geoclub wordt gehouden in Reggesteyn Noetsele en is voor de leerlingen en oudleerlingen van Reggesteyn. Onze leider is Mr. Nauta, een docent aardrijkskunde op Reggesteyn Noetsele. Bij de Geoclub hebben we het over stenen, fossielen en mineralen. We houden soms bijeenkomsten en excursies. Om de twee jaar houden we een grote, meerdaagse excursie. Hieronder kun je lezen over de bijeenkomsten en excursies. Verder kun je op onze website de agenda van de Geoclub bekijken en de foto's die we hebben genomen bekijken. Je kunt onder het tabblad 'contact' de adresgegevens van Mr. Nauta vinden. Veel plezier!</span></p>
        <p><span class="font2">De Bijeenkomsten</span><br><br><span class="font1">Ongeveer eens per maand houden we een bijeenkomst in lokaal 209 in het gebouw van Reggesteyn Noetsele, meestal om 14.45. Soms bereidt Mr. Nauta iets voor en soms bereidt een leerling iets voor. We eten en drinken halverwege ook iets. Als je wilt weten wanneer de bijeenkomsten zijn, kun je kijken op de agenda. Voor de exacte tijden en mogelijke wijzigingen stuurt Mr. Nauta je een mailtje. Zorg er dus voor dat hij je emailadres heeft. Mr. Nauta's emailadres kun je vinden onder 'contact'. Je bent altijd welkom bij een bijeenkomst, het is niet verplicht. Verder zijn de bijeenkomsten gratis.</span></p>
        <p><span class="font2">De Excursies</span><br><br><span class="font1">Met de Geoclub houden we ongeveer drie keer per jaar een excursie. Eens in de twee jaar houden we een grote, meerdaagse excursie. Meestal bereiden we in de bijeenkomst voor een excursie de excursie voor, en in de bijeenkomst na de excursie laten we onze vondsten zien. Tijdens de excursies gaan we een aantal groeves langs om te zoeken naar stenen, fossielen en mineralen. Mr. Nauta en enkele ouders rijden. We vertrekken meestal rond 9 uur en we zijn rond 5 uur weer terug. Bij de grote excursies gaan we drie tot vier dagen weg. We gaan dan bijvoorbeeld naar Duitsland of Frankrijk. We kamperen daar of we huren een huisje. We zoeken naar stenen, fossielen en mineralen in de buurt van waar we overnachten. In de periode voor de grote excursie krijg je meer duidelijke informatie over de excursie.<br><br>Bij de gewone excursies is het handig om de volgende dingen mee te nemen: eten en drinken, een (moker) hamer, een puntige steenbeitel en een platte steenbeitel, iets om je vondsten in te bewaren en wat closetpapier om breekbare vondsten in te bewaren.<br><br>De gewone excursies kosten ongeveer 10 euro (voor benzine). De grote excursies kosten rond de honderd euro (voor benzine, eten en overnachting).</span></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I halve my page, the text goes out of the white marked body part. Is there a way to solve this without setting my page at 120%? I'm looking for something that will automatically align the body to the text. (There might be some contrary properties in the CSS script.)

Thanks for trying!

Update:

I've tried removing the height:100%; property, but this is the result: (Run in full page.)

```css
html, body {cursor:url(files/cursor.cur),progress;}
html{background-color:blue;background-image:url(files/bg.jpg);background-attachment:fixed;background-position:center;background-size:cover;height:100%;}
body{width:80%;background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.75);margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;}
p{margin-right:10px;margin-left:10px;text-align: center;}
iframe{overflow:hidden;height:80%;width:100%;}
img{display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}
table{border-collapse:collapse;font-family:calibri;border-style:outset;border-color:#FFFF00;border-width:5px;}
td{font-size:16px;border-width:1px;border-style:solid;border-color:#FFFF00;background-color:#FFFFFF}
th{font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;background-color:#FFEE00;border-color:#FFFF00;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;}
a.active{background-color:#0088FF !important;}
a.active:hover{background-color:#00AAFF !important;}
.font1{font-family:calibri;font-size:16px;}
.font2{font-family:calibri;font-size:18px;text-decoration:underline;}
#menu1 a{display:block;background-color:#0066FF;text-decoration:none;font-family:calibri;font-size:20px;color:#FFFFFF;padding:10px 10px;} 
#menu1 a:hover{background-color:#00AAFF;} 
#menu1 li{display:inline-block;} 
#menu1 ul{list-style:none;text-align:center;margin:0 auto;padding:0px;}
#menu2 a{display:block;background-color:#0066FF;text-decoration:none;font-family:calibri;font-size:16px;color:#FFFFFF;padding:10px 10px;} 
#menu2 a:hover{background-color:#00AAFF;} 
#menu2 li{display:inline-block;}
#menu2 ul{list-style:none;text-align:center;margin:0 auto;padding:0px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>De Geoclub</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <br>
        <div id="menu1"><ul><li><a href="index.html">Welkom</a></li><li><a href="agenda.html">Agenda</a></li><li><a href="fotos.html">Foto's</a></li><li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li></ul></div>
        <p><span class="font2">De Geoclub</span><br><br><span class="font1">Welkom op de website van de Geoclub. De Geoclub wordt gehouden in Reggesteyn Noetsele en is voor de leerlingen en oudleerlingen van Reggesteyn. Onze leider is Mr. Nauta, een docent aardrijkskunde op Reggesteyn Noetsele. Bij de Geoclub hebben we het over stenen, fossielen en mineralen. We houden soms bijeenkomsten en excursies. Om de twee jaar houden we een grote, meerdaagse excursie. Hieronder kun je lezen over de bijeenkomsten en excursies. Verder kun je op onze website de agenda van de Geoclub bekijken en de foto's die we hebben genomen bekijken. Je kunt onder het tabblad 'contact' de adresgegevens van Mr. Nauta vinden. Veel plezier!</span></p>
        <p><span class="font2">De Bijeenkomsten</span><br><br><span class="font1">Ongeveer eens per maand houden we een bijeenkomst in lokaal 209 in het gebouw van Reggesteyn Noetsele, meestal om 14.45. Soms bereidt Mr. Nauta iets voor en soms bereidt een leerling iets voor. We eten en drinken halverwege ook iets. Als je wilt weten wanneer de bijeenkomsten zijn, kun je kijken op de agenda. Voor de exacte tijden en mogelijke wijzigingen stuurt Mr. Nauta je een mailtje. Zorg er dus voor dat hij je emailadres heeft. Mr. Nauta's emailadres kun je vinden onder 'contact'. Je bent altijd welkom bij een bijeenkomst, het is niet verplicht. Verder zijn de bijeenkomsten gratis.</span></p>
        <p><span class="font2">De Excursies</span><br><br><span class="font1">Met de Geoclub houden we ongeveer drie keer per jaar een excursie. Eens in de twee jaar houden we een grote, meerdaagse excursie. Meestal bereiden we in de bijeenkomst voor een excursie de excursie voor, en in de bijeenkomst na de excursie laten we onze vondsten zien. Tijdens de excursies gaan we een aantal groeves langs om te zoeken naar stenen, fossielen en mineralen. Mr. Nauta en enkele ouders rijden. We vertrekken meestal rond 9 uur en we zijn rond 5 uur weer terug. Bij de grote excursies gaan we drie tot vier dagen weg. We gaan dan bijvoorbeeld naar Duitsland of Frankrijk. We kamperen daar of we huren een huisje. We zoeken naar stenen, fossielen en mineralen in de buurt van waar we overnachten. In de periode voor de grote excursie krijg je meer duidelijke informatie over de excursie.<br><br>Bij de gewone excursies is het handig om de volgende dingen mee te nemen: eten en drinken, een (moker) hamer, een puntige steenbeitel en een platte steenbeitel, iets om je vondsten in te bewaren en wat closetpapier om breekbare vondsten in te bewaren.<br><br>De gewone excursies kosten ongeveer 10 euro (voor benzine). De grote excursies kosten rond de honderd euro (voor benzine, eten en overnachting).</span></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want the white body to reach to at least the bottom of the page but farther if the text exceeds the page. Sorry for not being clear.

Update:

Using the min-height property didn't work. The page remained as in snippet 2.

Comment: Run the snippet, press full page and resize the window to half the screen. You'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

It's caused by `height: 100%` on the body, remove it and the text is contained.

Answer (score 1):

Your body is set to `height: 100%;`.  Change it to `height: auto;`.  Otherwise the body stays the same height as the window even when it scrolls out of the way. If you want it to be at least the full height of the window you can set `min-height: 100%;`.

Comment: I suppose you mean min-height? I'll try that.

Comment: It didn't work. The page remains as in the second snippet. I removed all height properties from the body and html and then added this: html, body {min-height:100%;}

Comment: leave the html {height: 100%;} set body to {height: auto; min-height: 100%}.  You want the html to be the full height of the window but allow the body to be bigger than that (if the content pushes it bigger as in your case).  The min-height on body ensures that it is at least as big as the html.  A great way to see all of this is to use the Chrome developer tools.  As you hover over any element it will highlight the space it takes up.  You can change your css and see the effects immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Add `height: auto;` to `body` tag CSS instead of   `height: 100%;`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue is the collapsing margin between the bottom paragraph and the body.

You can work around it by adding either some padding or a border at the bottom of the body.

In my example, I added `padding-bottom: 1px` and this allows the body's background to fully enclose the height of the paragraph along with the paragraph's top and bottom margin.

You did not see this effect at the top of the page because you set the top margin of the `ul` that makes up the menu to zero.

You still need to set `min-height: 100%` on the body to extend the background color to the bottom of the page for cases where the height of the content does not fill up the page.  For safe measure, I added `box-sizing: border-box;` to compensate for the 1px padding.

In summary, you need the 1px padding to fix the collapsing margin problem for the case of the content being long enough to cause the page to scroll.  For the shorter pages, use `min-height: 100%` to force the body to extend to the bottom of the page (in this case, the collapsing margin issue may not show itself).

```css
html,
body {
  cursor: url(files/cursor.cur), progress;
}
html {
  background-color: blue;
  background-image: url(files/bg.jpg);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 1px; /* stops margins from collapsing */
  min-height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
p {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
iframe {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
}
img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: calibri;
  border-style: outset;
  border-color: #FFFF00;
  border-width: 5px;
}
td {
  font-size: 16px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #FFFF00;
  background-color: #FFFFFF
}
th {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #FFEE00;
  border-color: #FFFF00;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}
a.active {
  background-color: #0088FF !important;
}
a.active:hover {
  background-color: #00AAFF !important;
}
.font1 {
  font-family: calibri;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.font2 {
  font-family: calibri;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
#menu1 a {
  display: block;
  background-color: #0066FF;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: calibri;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}
#menu1 a:hover {
  background-color: #00AAFF;
}
#menu1 li {
  display: inline-block;
}
#menu1 ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px;
}
#menu2 a {
  display: block;
  background-color: #0066FF;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: calibri;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}
#menu2 a:hover {
  background-color: #00AAFF;
}
#menu2 li {
  display: inline-block;
}
#menu2 ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu1">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Welkom</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="agenda.html">Agenda</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="fotos.html">Foto's</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <p><span class="font2">De Geoclub</span>
    <br>
    <br><span class="font1">Welkom op de website van de Geoclub. De Geoclub wordt gehouden in Reggesteyn Noetsele en is voor de leerlingen en oudleerlingen van Reggesteyn. Onze leider is Mr. Nauta, een docent aardrijkskunde op Reggesteyn Noetsele. Bij de Geoclub hebben we het over stenen, fossielen en mineralen. We houden soms bijeenkomsten en excursies. Om de twee jaar houden we een grote, meerdaagse excursie. Hieronder kun je lezen over de bijeenkomsten en excursies. Verder kun je op onze website de agenda van de Geoclub bekijken en de foto's die we hebben genomen bekijken. Je kunt onder het tabblad 'contact' de adresgegevens van Mr. Nauta vinden. Veel plezier!</span>
  </p>
  <p><span class="font2">De Bijeenkomsten</span>
    <br>
    <br><span class="font1">Ongeveer eens per maand houden we een bijeenkomst in lokaal 209 in het gebouw van Reggesteyn Noetsele, meestal om 14.45. Soms bereidt Mr. Nauta iets voor en soms bereidt een leerling iets voor. We eten en drinken halverwege ook iets. Als je wilt weten wanneer de bijeenkomsten zijn, kun je kijken op de agenda. Voor de exacte tijden en mogelijke wijzigingen stuurt Mr. Nauta je een mailtje. Zorg er dus voor dat hij je emailadres heeft. Mr. Nauta's emailadres kun je vinden onder 'contact'. Je bent altijd welkom bij een bijeenkomst, het is niet verplicht. Verder zijn de bijeenkomsten gratis.</span>
  </p>
  <p><span class="font2">De Excursies</span>
    <br>
    <br><span class="font1">Met de Geoclub houden we ongeveer drie keer per jaar een excursie. Eens in de twee jaar houden we een grote, meerdaagse excursie. Meestal bereiden we in de bijeenkomst voor een excursie de excursie voor, en in de bijeenkomst na de excursie laten we onze vondsten zien. Tijdens de excursies gaan we een aantal groeves langs om te zoeken naar stenen, fossielen en mineralen. Mr. Nauta en enkele ouders rijden. We vertrekken meestal rond 9 uur en we zijn rond 5 uur weer terug. Bij de grote excursies gaan we drie tot vier dagen weg. We gaan dan bijvoorbeeld naar Duitsland of Frankrijk. We kamperen daar of we huren een huisje. We zoeken naar stenen, fossielen en mineralen in de buurt van waar we overnachten. In de periode voor de grote excursie krijg je meer duidelijke informatie over de excursie.<br><br>Bij de gewone excursies is het handig om de volgende dingen mee te nemen: eten en drinken, een (moker) hamer, een puntige steenbeitel en een platte steenbeitel, iets om je vondsten in te bewaren en wat closetpapier om breekbare vondsten in te bewaren.<br><br>De gewone excursies kosten ongeveer 10 euro (voor benzine). De grote excursies kosten rond de honderd euro (voor benzine, eten en overnachting).</span>
  </p>
```